# Orthonormal basis for the Lebesgue spaces on unit sphere

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathbb{S}_n$ be the $n$-dimensional unit sphere and let $\mathbb{T}^n$ be the $n$-dimensional torus. Let us consider $L^2(\mathbb{S}_n)$ and $L^2(\mathbb{T}^n)$. We know that $\{{z_1}^{k_1}\ldots{z_n}^{k_n}:k_i\in\mathbb{Z}, |z_i|=1,i=1,\ldots,n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{T}^n)$. What can we say about an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{S}_n)$? Any reference will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Look up spherical harmonics for a particularly nice choice.